# Zombie http.proxyHost settings for JVM on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, proxy, jvm

I recently changed network and removed all my HTTP proxy settings from the System Preferences / Networking panel on OSX (Leopard). However, now whenever I use Eclipse the Java HTTP proxy system properties seem to be 'automagically' set to use my now defunct HTTP proxy.

I can find **no direct reference** to this proxy **anywhere** on my system, have deleted and reinstalled Eclipse, have monitored the network traffic to rule out any proxy auto configuration, and yet this proxy configuration persists on the Mac OSX JVM.

This is what I see in the Eclipse configuration details:

```
http.proxyHost=zombie
http.proxyPort=8080
https.proxyHost=zombie
https.proxyPort=8080
```

I can work around this by manually configuring a proxy with no host name or port in the Eclipse preferences, but this doesn't seem to stick and the zombie system proxy eventually rises from the dead.

Personally I think that this is some kind of Apple JVM bug - but can anyone tell me how I can kill these zombie HTTP proxy settings for good without reinstalling my operating system?

Comment: I have been unable to resolve this problem as yet. The proxy still returns occasionally despite the assistance given in the answers. I will reinstall OSX at some point which should resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue, did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: I got the same issue in Android studio proxy settings

Answer (score 3):

Check the values in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/lib/net.properties
```

There are comments in that file saying proxy settings (from net.properties) are used only *if there are no proxy settings in System Preferences*.  I'm wondering if something updated your net.properties file, setting proxy info.  Now that you have no proxy settings (in System Preferences), the values in net.properties are actually being used.

Comment: I checked the file in question and in contains no active properties. They are all commented out with the exception of the no-op property:

java.net.useSystemProxies=false

Answer (score 2):

You reinstall eclipse, but did you:

- removed your old workspace ?
- have any environment variable like:
  `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxyHost=host.example.com -Dhttp.proxyHost=7777`
- observed the java process of your eclipse, to see if it was executed with options like:
  `java -classpath ./bin -Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.mydomain.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
  -Dhttp.noProxyHosts=”localhost|host.mydomain.com”`

Comment: Old workspace removed. JAVA_OPTS is not set. Process does not show any system properties being set. I should note that I am using MyEclipse - not the vanilla version.

Comment: It could be interesting to check with a plain Eclipse and see if it also picks the old settings...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you guys are mission something. Check out the comment for that property

```
# MacOSX:
# On MacOSX, setting java.net.useSystemProxies to true or false is a no-op.
# Proxy settings from System Preferences are always used and they override any
# settings specified in this file. Values from this file are only used if there
# are no proxy settings in System Preferences.
# See Release Notes for more information.

java.net.useSystemProxies=false
```