# Eclipse still using http.proxyHost settings when no longer set

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, jvm

I'm dealing with the same sort of problem as "[Zombie http.proxyHost settings for JVM on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619567/zombie-http-proxyhost-settings-for-jvm-on-osx)" except I'm on Kubuntu 8.04 and Eclipse 3.4.2. I had to use a proxy for work but have migrated off it. I've reset everything in my environment I can find inside and outside Eclipse to get rid of setting the proxy. However when I try to use the Software Update feature I find it's still using the proxy. In the error log I can see:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2009-03-17 10:49:50.137 !MESSAGE System property http.proxyHost has been set to netproxy.blah.com by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2009-03-17 10:49:50.164 !MESSAGE System property http.proxyPort has been set to 3128 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

Any ideas as to what the external source might be that's setting this property?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Show your support and open an issue in Bugzilla.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug in the preferences panel. You can see it if you tail your workspace/.metadata/.log file.

The workaround (at least in Eclipse 3.4.2) is:

- Open **Window > Preferences**, then **General > Network Connections**
- Select **Manual proxy configuration**
- Click the **Add Host...** button  to add a 'No Proxy' entry
- Enter a random entry, say 'localhost' and click **OK**
- Click **Direct connection to the Internet**
- Close the property panel with the **OK** button.

Comment: Crazy? Still a problem in 4.5.2.

Answer (score 3):

Or go to your *eclipse.ini* file and check if there are some parameters like :

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy
-Dhttp.proxyUser=mydomain\myusername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

OR same parameters but the first one finishes in 4 like below:

```
  -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

Since release of Eclipse Kepler (4.3)

With this parameters you can disable the HttpClient provider and have ECF use the JRE URLConnection-based provider instead(line 1). And set proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had a similar problem with the mantis mylyn connector. I don't remember where exactly the entry was, but I think somewhere in the metadata folder of your workspace was an option file for this particualar plugin. Maybe something similar exists for your problem.
On a windows system I've already found eclipse settings in the application folder of the users home directory. Not sure though how this is handled on Ubuntu... it's been a while.

Worst case you could just install another eclipse instance and see if that works. Although if the config file responsible for this problem is not somewhere in the eclipse folder, you'll still have the same problem.

At least you'll have a hint about where it is - eclipse folder, workspace or system setting in home folder.

Greetings and good luck!